# JOIN getting id value from wrong table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a join similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN `columns` c ON u.id = c.user_id WHERE ....
```

However, when I iterate through the result set, I find that the `id` field from the wrong table is getting referenced when I echo out `$row['id'];`. It is `echo`ing out the id from the `columns` table instead of the one from the `users` table.

I tried doing something like : `echo $row['u.id'];` but I got an undefined index error.

I was wondering why this is and how I can fix it?

I appreciate any advice,

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try like this, SELECT *,users.id as user_id FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN `columns` c ON u.id = c.user_id

Comment: I would like to suggest a thing is possible, go to PHP my admin and execute your query with some hardcoded parameters. Look at the result and accordingly, fix your query/watch if the column has been renamed.

Comment: @kfirba: that is not at all the problem. This is simply an issue of failing to use column aliases or explicit column names in the `SELECT` statement. The query is otherwise fine.

Comment: @siride Well, I just suggested my way of debugging. When things like that happens to me, thats what im doing and trying to alter the query until i get the result i desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this issue because MySQL is returning two different `id` columns, one from each table. To resolve this ambiguity, you can alias the columns you need to names that you can guarantee are unique.

For example:

```
SELECT u.id AS `users-id`, u.next_column
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN columns c...
```

So in your php, you can:

```
echo $row['users-id'];
```

Comment: Yes, but I have 40+ columns I need to select, so I need to do u.id AS ..., u.name, u.color, etc...?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend: yes, it's best practice to do this.

Comment: +1, thank you, this worked well. I found a work around that requires less typing, I can just do u.*, c.*, u.id AS `uid`, this solved my problem.